# Ceiling Fan Installed now wall outlet does not work

Tags: fans

I have installed a ceiling fan and it is working. The wall outlets however, are not.  The room has no light switch.

On the ceiling there were two black wires and two white wires (there is also a brown wire, that is unused). I am assuming they were set up in series.

When I used all of them and tried to connect the +/- for the fan, the fan did not work. When I disconnected both black and white wires and connected only one of them to the fan, all was fine there, but now the wall outlets have no power.

How can I resolve this??

Comment: How were the wires connected before you installed the fan?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: The previous fan was old with a chain system for light and fan.  The two black (I believe one coming from fuse box and the other going to the wall outlets) were connected together and connected to the red for the fan.  Same with white wires.  The brown was disconnected.  Green to ground.  I first attempted to connect the new fan in the same way but did not work. Then, took the outgoing white and blacks out.  But now no power on wall outlets

Comment: What wire colors does the new fan have? Or what make and model is it, for that matter?

Comment: First help me straighten out your terminology, and exactly what you meant.
We don't use +/- in AC circuits, so it's hot and neutral, layman's terms.
Not picking, just so others can follow you better.
Then you said you hooked up 'just one' to the fan. It wouldn't work with just one wire, so I assume you hooked up one black and one white?
What kind of testers/meters do you have available?
I don't know how a brown got in there; is there any chance they covered up the old switch box? Try a stud sensor with AC sensing (or metal maybe), and explore around the doorway area some...